# Samsung Galaxy Tab AVD with Google API?

Tags: android, tabs

I installed the add-on [provided by Samsung](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do) so I could create an AVD that would emulate a Galaxy Tab, but unfortunately my most important project uses the Google API (for using the Maps external library) which is not supported by the single additional target that the add-on provides. Does anyone know of any way to have an AVD for the Tab *with* support for the Google API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the above posting got mangled.
here it is again.

1. copy (android sdk)/add-ons/(galaxy target/skins/*.* to (android sdk)/add-ons/(google target)
2. edit the manifest file in the directory for (google target)
3. add "skin=GALAXY Tab" (without quotes) to the manifest file.  The google target will now launch without the system default and instead use the skin info from Samsung.

Comment: I believe this is far from a solution. This hack is not emulating the galaxy tab, this is only the google api avd with the galaxy tab look. The OS is still the same as before (as you will be using the SO images from the google api emulator folder).

Answer (score 1):

The `GalaxyTAB AVD` does not have the `Google API`s, the only way I got a real tablet emulator with `Google API`s was creating a virtual machine, using one of [these](http://code.google.com/p/androbox/downloads/list) `Android` images and a virtualization software, such as `Virtual Box`. Then associating the `Android` virtual machine with `eclipse`, detailed instructions can be found [here](http://www.bhecker.com/ap-emulator.txt)

p.s: This also yields a *much* faster emulator experience.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found a solution.  On my Mac development machine here is what 
I did.

1. copy /add-ons//skin/*.* to /add-ons/
2. edit the manifest file in directory for your google target
3. add "skin=GALAXY Tab"  (without the quotes) to the manifest file. The google
   target will now launch without the system default and instead use the skin info from
   Samsung defined in the skin folder.

hope this helps